# Using minecrafts plugin Skript - How to make a loop, that checks, if player goes in WorldGuard region?

Tags: minecraft

So, I wanna make a loop, that checks, if player goes in WorldGuard region. I don't have any specific details, just i wanna know how to do it.

This is how my code looks like:

```
set {_rg::*} to %region at player%
loop {_rg::*}:
    if "%loop-value%" contains "fail1_1"
        execute console command "tp %player% -425.5 9.87500 2299.767 0.0 50.0"
    if "%loop-value%" contains "fail1_2":
        execute console command "tp %player% -425.5 10 2304.5 0.0 50.0"
```

Im not really an expert, but i tried to look it up. So, nothing really happened, there were no errors, but it didn't work as i expected (if you fall into region, you get teleported to a location)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is most likely that your Skript installation is broken, your code should give multiple errors that make you aware why your code is not working. Try the latest version of Skript that is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SkriptLang/Skript/releases).

---

> ```
> set {_rg::*} to %region at player%
> ```

If you are not working inside a text, you can't use the percentage signs, these are made to interpolate the given variable to text. Skript would create a working `{_rg:*}` list variable without the percentage signs.

You could use the percentage signs if you wanted to message at which regions the player is:

```
message "Regions: %region at player%" to player
```

---

> ```
> if "%loop-value%" contains "fail1_1"
> ```

A colon is missing at the end of this statement, which should lead to errors while parsing.

---

> ```
> execute console command "tp %player% -425.5 9.87500 2299.767 0.0 50.0"
> ```

While you can execute commands to teleport players using Skript, you can also teleport players without executing console commands. The reason for this is that Skript will not check if the command is going to work.

Instead, you can use the [location](https://docs.skriptlang.org/functions.html#location) function to create a new location and teleport the player to it.

```
teleport player to location(-425.5, 9.87500, 2299.767, player's world, 0.0, 50.0)
```